# Teamcity and localdb

Tags: sql-server, teamcity

I've got some tests, which run on sqllocaldb instance. I also have Teamcity CI server on the same PC (don't ask me why). But when I am running tests from TeamCity, I receive this error

> OneTimeSetUp: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related
>   or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50
>   - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

While running tests inside VS is OK. What's the reason TeamCity can't see this localDB stuff?

Comment: Is TeamCity running as a "service"?  Is the service running as "Local System", "Network Service" or some utility account?

Comment: TeamCIty is running as service, 'Local System', default settings, still I've found some workaround

Answer (score 0):

In this case it worked to launch nunit-console from command prompt runner.
TeamCity catches the resulting output and shows failed/succeded tests, with the right connection to localDB instance